# Format an Excel cell from R if a cell is not blank

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I am trying to format a cell in a particular column in Excel from R (producing a workbook using a dataframe). I am currently using `openxlsx`.

This is the line of code that I am currently trying to get to work:

`conditionalFormatting(WorkBook, "Sheet1", cols=17, rows=1:11000, rule='<TODAY(),"<>"&""', style = negStyle)`

I have also tried this:

`conditionalFormatting(WorkBook, "Sheet1", cols=17, rows=1:11000, rule='AND(<TODAY(),"<>"&"")', style = negStyle)`

and

`conditionalFormatting(WorkBook, "Sheet1", cols=17, rows=1:11000, rule='AND(<TODAY(),<>&"")', style = negStyle)`

So I am  trying to style the cell with `negStyle` if the date in the column is earlier than today's date. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `conditionalFormatting` formula in Excel will be something like:
[image]

So if you want to apply this formatting using `openxlsx`, you will need to do:

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "cond")

date_df <- data.frame(id = 1:20,
                      dat_col = as.Date("2019-09-20")-1:20)

writeData(wb, "cond", date_df)

negStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "#9C0006", bgFill = "#FFC7CE")
conditionalFormatting(wb, "cond", cols=2, rows=2:21, rule="<TODAY()", style = negStyle)
saveWorkbook(wb, "test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Then you will get:

[image]

**EDIT**

If you only want to apply the formatting on non empty cells then you can do this by updating `rule` as: `'AND(b2<TODAY(), b2<>"")'`

```
library(openxlsx)

set.seed(111)
date_df <- data.frame(id = 1:20,
                      dat_col = as.Date("2019-09-20")-1:20)

# Shuffle data frame
date_df <- date_df[sample(nrow(date_df)), ]

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "cond")

writeData(wb, "cond", date_df[1:8,], )

writeData(wb, "cond", date_df[9:10, ], startRow = 11, colNames = FALSE )
writeData(wb, "cond", date_df[11:20,], startRow = 15, colNames = FALSE)


negStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "#9C0006", bgFill = "#FFC7CE")

conditionalFormatting(wb, "cond", cols=2, rows=2:24, rule='AND(b2<TODAY(), b2<>"")', style = negStyle)
saveWorkbook(wb, "test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Sorry  I should have specified  but my issue is that some of the cells are empty. Not only does this rules corrently format cells with dates before today's date, but it unfortunately also formats empty cells!

Comment: @Dieu94 Just updated the answer. Update the rule as: `'AND(b2<TODAY(), b2<>"")'`

Comment: What does b2 refer to?

Comment: `b2` refers to the Excel cell. So basically this is the cell for the conditional formatting rule

Comment: But isn't that then fixed? How does it apply down the whole column?

Comment: It will be fixed if you lock `b2`, i.e. if we put `$` so if it was `$b$2` then it is locked but because current rule is set up as `b2` the formula will apply to the whole column.